# Error al descarga de pdf con php

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy tratando de hacer que el usuario descargue un archivo pdf con php, el problema es que cuando se descargan los archivos me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$file="$file.pdf";
$filename = $this->config->item('RUTA_CFDi').$file;
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile($filename);
```

Ya verifique que los archivos esten bien, lo extraño es que algunos archivos si los descarga bien y otro no, salen con el error de la imagen.

No se si alguien sepa a que se debe este error, y como puedo solucionarlo, o alguna otra forma de descargar archivos pdf, con php.

Comment: verificastes si tienes permiso de escribir en la ruta? o si esta el pdf en la ruta mencionada

Comment: si, las dos cosas las verifique, como comente algunos archivos los descarga bien pero otros no.

Comment: Si los archivos PDF están comprobados, puede ser un problema asociado al nombre de los archivos, tienen caracteres especiales o espacios los que fallan?

Comment: cuando fallan generalmente es que el archivo no se encuentra puede ser un espacio en blanco de mas en el nombre u otro caracter

Comment: Bueno ya note que en algunos casos les agrega muchos espacios en blanco en el nombre al descargarlos, ya que cuando le mando el path va bien sin espacios en blanco.

Comment: puedes probar lo siguiente, copia en el servidor el nombre del archivo y haz un var_dump del documento a visualizar y compara el largo de los string

Comment: Gracias, cheque la longitud del path y no entiendo porque a algunos les agregaba espacios en blanco, entonces lo que hice fue remover todos los espacios en blanco de path con preg_replace y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema similar al crear un archivo pdf, obtenía toda la información de la base de datos y me daba error cuando no se subía bien la imagen osea que no existiera. Eso lo note asta que verifique cada imagen si existiera insertada.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me mostraba ese error y solo le quite esta linea al header
header('Content-Length: ' . $img['size']);

y asi lo solucione porque el tamaño no lo estaba calculando bien.

Saludos

Answer (score -4):

Normalmente ***bastará con poner un enlace al PDF***, dentro del código HTML, ***como si enlazaras cualquier otro recurso***. Si el PDF esta en la ubicación a la que apunta el enlace se abrirá o descargará automáticamente.

Como manejas la carga de PDFs, su creación, etc es independiente de como vas a disponer su descarga. Salvo que los estés generando en el momento.

**Editado.**

Esta respuesta es al problema concreto:

> Error al descarga de pdf con php
>
> Estoy tratando de hacer que el
> usuario descargue un archivo pdf con php, el problema es que cuando se
> descargan los archivos me sale el siguiente error:

es decir, **indico el código HTML necesario para poder descargar un fichero PDF**, como se carga, se genera, etc son otras cuestiones que tal vez requieran el replanteamiento del presente post en cuyo contenido actual se mezclan varios conceptos.

**Para que un PDF sea descargable**, sólo se requiere un enlace HTML que enlace el recurso y situar éste en la carpeta pública de un sitio web (lo he enlazado con una ruta absoluta):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Descarga PDF</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.cambialibros.es/public/test.pdf">pdf ejemplo</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Si creas un fichero HTML con el código anterior y lo abres en tu navegador, al hacer clic, se abrirá o descargará el fichero PDF.

Comment: Esta no es una respuesta

Comment: @Fabian Montoya, y por eso los votos negativos. Edite mi respuesta.